# I'm trying to get my program to a certain number of times equivalent to the amount I enter but I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: python, loops

Hi first time posting here. So basically if I type "1" it'll loop 5 times while if I type 5 it does the complete opposite. How do I type "1" and get it to loop once, "2" to get it to loop twice, etc? Additionally, my assignment requires me to make it so that it'll repeatedly ask me those questions if I don't give an answer from 1 to 5, but idk how to do it.

```
drink = int(input("How many drinks will you consume? "))
while(drink == 1):
    print("You've consumed " + str(drink) + " drinks")
while(drink == 2):
    print("You've consumed " + str(drink) + " drinks")
    drink = drink + 1
while(drink == 3):
    print("You've consumed " + str(drink) + " drinks")
    drink = drink + 1
while(drink == 4):
    print("You've consumed " + str(drink) + " drinks")
    drink = drink + 1
while(drink == 5):
    print("You've consumed " + str(drink) + " drinks")
    drink = drink + 1    
print("You're done drinking.")
```

since that didn't work I also tried a for loop which also didn't work as intended:

```
drink = int(input("How many drinks will you consume? "))
for drink in range(1, 6, 1):
    print("You've consumed " + str(drink) + " drinks")
print("You're done drinking.")
```

In this case any number I type between 1 to 5 will always churn out 5 loops. What is the answer to this problem? I've worked on it for 2 hours and feel stupid.

Comment:  http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: In your first code, if you type `1`, you have an infinite loop… If you understand why, you're on your way to understanding the rest too…

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that you should use a for loop, however, juts done it slightly wrong. Try this:

```
drink = int(input("How many drinks will you consume? "))
for i in range(drink):
    print(f"You have had {i + 1} drinks")
print("You are done drinking")
```

Comment: You probably want to start the `range` at `1`…

Comment: Thank you both for corrections

Comment: `f'... drink{"" if i == 1 else "s"}'`… ;)

Comment: You should put it as if i == 0 as that is the first element (i.e. first drink)

Comment: That's why you should start the `range` at `1`, to have more semantic code and avoid such bugs… ;)

Comment: Fair point, didn't think about that